# Serve resources in place with Maven in Eclipse

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven Eclipse project with some special resource folder: www-build. I added it to pom.xml to get maven to use it for resources:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>www-build</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
...
</build>
```

I noticed that Maven does not serve those files in place from resource folders, but always copies them target directory first. As the latter sometimes appears to mysteriously not work for some people, I am wondering:

Is it possible to get Maven/Eclipse to serve resources from www-build directly, without copying to target? Why does it copy to target?

Answer (score 1):

You have not said how you are running the webapp.

If you are running the webapp via built in Eclipse functionality, there is an alternative plugin for eclipse: [webby](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Integration+with+Maven+WAR+Plugin) that should do what you are after (I don't use eclipse so I cannot confirm)

If you are running the servlet container via a maven plugin, eg jetty-maven-plugin or tomcat-maven-plugin then this may just depend on the plugin goal you are using....

I have been working on an alternative, more “web like” maven plugin: [jszip.org](http://jszip.org) it is still in alpha and I haven't had the spare time to move it forward for the past couple of months, but I should be getting some cycles again sometime soon.

Finally, if these are classpath resources, *technically* picking up changes in them should involve restarting the entire web application as the container manager has no way to evaluate the scope/impact of changing a file on the classpath, so such changes should trigger a context restart... Which is safest if you do the context tear-down with the original classpath, update the classpath and then set-up replacement context... That would be easier to do if the classpath resources are copied into a "working" directory that the app is started from

Answer (score 0):

A ressource is something that is part of your program and therefore is packaged with your program. When packaging is done by Maven, it copies everything that belongs to the package to the target directory.

If you do not need this behaviour the contents of your folder might not be a ressource by definition. Could you maybe set it up as a dependency?